# Is it possible to solve Non-Divisible Subset by HackerRank via Dynamic Programming?

Tags: c++

What I mean by this is that you basically create a tree of all available subsets `S'` of a given set `S` but "cut off" subsets which are divisible by `k` as early as possible (e.g. if a subset of two numbers is already divisible by `k` then a subset of three numbers including this subset is going to be also divisible by `k`).

I know that there is a faster solution with remainders of `% k` but I don't understand that solution so I would rather stick with my initial idea of dynamic programming.

Unfortunately, I am not able to come up with the recursive formula and / or which data I need from the previous subset to calculate the next subset.

Any tips / tricks for this problem?

I don't know if I am allowed to post the exercise here as it might be property of `HackerRank` but I am sure you are aware the problem I am describing.

Edit: The task is to find the `size` of the largest subset `S'` of a set `S` where no two numbers of `S'` are evenly divisible by `k`.

Comment: I could be reading your process wrong, but... Creating all possible results, then pruning 
 to remove undesirables typically means you did the maximum possible work and then added on more work to clean up. Your approach probably can produce the desired output, but I suspect it won't meet the performance target.

Comment: *"I don't know if I am allowed to post the exercise here as it might be property of HackerRank"* -- the usual solution to this is to think abstractly and isolate your issue to the point where the original problem no longer needs to be mentioned. If your question is not self-contained, it is off-topic for SO.

Comment: *"but I am sure you are aware the problem I am describing."* -- being sure does not make your conclusion correct. I am not aware of the problem you are describing, and when I try to fill in the omitted information, your description does not make sense to me. Possibly, I could try other interpretations, but that is more work than I should have to put into this.

Comment: @user4581301 I wasn't saying what you described. I said to cut off unsuccessful branches  as early as possible, not as late as possible

Comment: @JaMiT I added the problem description

Comment: @binaryBigInt Okaaay.... Definitely not close to what I was thinking. In fact, I don't see why you would even consider dynamic programming for an O(n) problem. I guess this is another example of one of those cheesy hack-site problems that require a mathematical trick instead of programming skills.

Comment: @JaMiT Because if you don't know the math trick this is basically the only option left to get reasonable runtime